# Understanding Convolution in K-Theory via an example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I've spent lots of time in Chriss and Ginzburg's "Complex Geometry and Representation Theory" and despite convolution (in Borel-Moore homology or K-theory) being very central, I feel like I'm still lacking a little understanding. I'd like some help with the following example.

On the representation theory side, I'd like to consider the following simple example. Let $G=SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and let $T \subset B$ be the toral subgroup of diagonal matrices and the Borel subgroup consisting of upper triangular matrices respectively. Let $V_{\Lambda_1}$ denote the irreducible representation of highest weight $\Lambda_1$. Taking the tensor square of this representation yields the following decomposition into irreducibles: $V_{\Lambda_1} \otimes V_{\Lambda_1} \simeq V_{2 \Lambda_1} \oplus V_0$.

I'd like to geometrize this a la Ginzburg.

Via Borel-Weil, we know that $H^{0}(G/B, L_{\Lambda_1}) \simeq V_{\Lambda_1}$, where $L_{\Lambda_1}$ is the associated bundle $G \times_{B} \mathbb{C}^{-\Lambda_1}$. What I would like is an operation on $G$-equivariant sheaves which corresponds to the tensor product of representations, so that $H^0(G/B, L_{\Lambda_1} * L_{\Lambda_1}) \simeq V_{2 \Lambda_1} \oplus V_0$. Note that the operation cannot be the tensor product. To see this, remember that $G/B = \mathbb{P}^1$, and $L_{\Lambda_1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$; if I tensor this sheaf with itself and take global sections I will get the irreducible 3-dimensional representation $Sym^2(V_{\Lambda_1})=V_{2\Lambda_1}$.

Here is where I know that $*$ is supposed to be convolution, as defined by Ginzburg. (If anyone would like the definition, I can provide it, but that would lengthen this post even more).

Question 1: Is it correct to expect that $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) *\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) \simeq \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) \oplus \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$? This is the only way I can see the global sections giving me the correct representation.

Question 2: If this is indeed the case, is there an explicit description in terms of global sections $T_1, T_2$ of $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$, if the coordinates on $G/B=\mathbb{P}^1$ are $[T_1:T_2]$? It is easy to get the global sections $T_1^2, T_1T_2, T_2^2$ as a basis for $V_{2 \Lambda_1}$, but I cannot see how to get the basis for $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$.

I've got more thoughts, but I think this is already quite long for a post. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: Maybe I should move this to MathOverflow?

Comment: I think you should indeed

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Convolution in K-Theory via an Example (From StackExchange)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/338580). (As [suggested on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088), it's good to link to other copies when posting on multiple sites.)